# Один одного, одна одного чи одне одного?

Tags: вибір-слова, узгодження-слів

В художній літературі часто зустрічаємо вислів *"...один одного"*. Наприклад: "Вони люблять *один одного*" чи "Вони розуміють *один одного*". В англійській мові відповідником є "*each other*"  — "They love each other". Але в англійській мові не потрібно узгоджувати роди, на відміну від української. То ж як правильно казати: "Вони люблять одна одного", "Вони люблять одне одного" чи "Вони люблять один одного", якщо мова йде про жінку та чоловіка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

О. Авраменко у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3nfSPh8zJY) проводить експрес-урок якраз на Вашу тематику. Він відповідає на питання "Не бачимо ОДИН одного чи ОДНЕ одного?" так:

> займенник "**один одного**" використовують тоді, коли мова іде ЛИШЕ про чоловіків:
>
> *Брати давно не бачили один одного;*
>
> займенник "**одна одну**" - ЛИШЕ для позначення осіб жіночої статі:
>
> *Сестри давно не бачили одна одну;*
>
> Якщо мова іде про осіб різної статі, то слід використовувати **"одне одного"**.

Отож, у випадку, що наводите Ви, де йдеться про кохання, мало би бути так: "Вони люблять одне одного"